# java sparse matrix problem

Tags: java, performance, math, sparse-matrix

I have two dimensional matrix. My matrix is sparse. I am facing performance problem. Can any body please answer that what api or class i can use in java to handle sparse matrix to improve my program performance.

For example I want

```
it take 100x100 matrix
handle sparse stuff
do the multiplication
return me my matrix same as 100x100 with 0 ( mean sparse matrix )
```

Comment: It'd help to know what your current implementation is? Additionally, which data structures are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Jama is awful for large sparse matrices.

Have a look at the [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/) linear algebra library.

---

Another possibility for sparse linear algebra is [the apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/linear/package-summary.html) library. Might be a little lighter-weight than Colt but the difference from the look-and-feel of Jama might be a little larger.

Comment: @mobrule: How is Fortran for that? Because in the very link you gave it is written that Java is gaining more and more adoption and can reach 90% of the speed of Fortran. How is 90% of Fortran's speed? Is that awful? (btw I'm doing heavy number crunching in Java)

Comment: @Wizard, Fortran is a compiled language, like C. You are not going to get anything faster unless you write it in assembly.

Comment: is there anyother solution ?? coz colt is very big and i can't use very big api for this purpose :(

Comment: @agazerboy - the part of the API you need --
http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html for matrix objects and  http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/package-summary.html for SVD/linear-algebra are not so large. Are you working on an embedded system or something?

Answer (score 1):

[SuanShu](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/algebra/linear/matrix/doubles/matrixtype/sparse/package-summary.html) has a large collection of sparse matrices implemented. You can simply use those instead writing your own.

They currently support these formats: CSR, DOK, LIL

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java). The la4j supports sparse matrices as well as dense ones. Here is the list of supported matrix types: 1D-Array (dense), 2D-Array (dense), CRS - Compressed Row Storage (sparse), CCS - Compressed Column Storage (sparse).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Jama? http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/ - they don't directly support sparse matrices, but it's a widely used package.

Also, princeton seems to have a sparse matrix implementation for you to take a look at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/44st/SparseMatrix.java.html

Comment: I am using jama for SVD. Can you point out how can I use jama for this purpose? I think jama is for dense matrix